# reactjs form: with two submit buttons doing two different tasks for same form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I want to have two submit buttons for my form.

Both will use the same inputs and form validation, but will do different tasks

```
export default function Formtwosubmits() {

  function handlesubmit_task1(){


  }


  function handlesubmit_task2(){


  }


  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handlesubmit_task1 if task 1 button pressed || handlesubmit_task2 if task2 button pressed } >
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
          task 1
        </Button>

        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
          task 2
        </Button>
        .... here input fields
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am not able to undertand how to pass different handlesumit functions for different buttons

I have tried:

```
export default function Formtwosubmits() {

  function handlesubmit_task1(){


  }


  function handlesubmit_task2(){


  }


  return (
    <>
      <form >
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit" onClick={handlesubmit_task1}>
          task 1
        </Button>

        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit" onClick={handlesubmit_task2}>
          task 2
        </Button>
        .... here input fields
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

putting `onClick` on the button. with `type=submit` but this does not check the form validation (like required etc), whereas with onSubmit i see the form validation is checked

How can i trigger form validation with `onClick`. even that can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a React ref on the `form` element to access the form fields in the submit handlers and attach the submit handlers to each button's `onClick` handler.

```
function Formtwosubmits() {
  const formRef = useRef(); // (1) <-- React ref for form DOMNode

  function handlesubmit_task1(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { value } = formRef.current.myInput; // (4) <-- access form inputs by name

    // ...anything you need to do with form fields
    console.log("handler 1", value);

    formRef.current.reset(); // (5) <-- reset form if necessary
  }
  
  function handlesubmit_task2(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { value } = formRef.current.myInput;

    console.log("handler 2", value);

    formRef.current.reset();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form ref={formRef}> // (2) <-- Attach ref to element
        <button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          type="submit"
          onClick={handlesubmit_task1} // (3) <-- Attach submit handler 1
        >
          task 1
        </button>
        <button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          type="submit"
          onClick={handlesubmit_task2} // (3) <-- Attach submit handler 2
        >
          task 2
        </button>
        .... here input fields
        <input name="myInput" type="text" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit reactjs-form-with-two-submit-buttons-doing-two-different-tasks-for-same-form]

## Update

You can assign an `id` to each submit button and access the [React Synthetic event's `nativeEvent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) to get to the underlying browser event and access the [submitter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter) value.

Create a `submitHandler` to receive the form's `onSubmit` event and check the submitter value and proxy the `onSubmit` event to the proper handler based on `id`.

```
const handlers = {
  submit1: handlesubmit_task1,
  submit2: handlesubmit_task2,
}

const submitHandler = (e) => {
  const { id } = e.nativeEvent.submitter; // <-- access submitter id
  handlers[id](e); // <--proxy event to proper callback handler
};

function handlesubmit_task1(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { value } = event.target.myInput;
  console.log("handler 1", value);
  event.target.reset();
}

function handlesubmit_task2(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { value } = event.target.myInput;
  console.log("handler 2", value);
  event.target.reset();
}

<form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
  <button
    id="submit1" // <-- id 1
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    type="submit"
  >
    task 1
  </button>
  <button
    id="submit2" // <-- id 2
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    type="submit"
  >
    task 2
  </button>
  .... here input fields
  <input name="myInput" type="text" />
</form>
```

[image: Edit reactjs-form-with-two-submit-buttons-doing-two-different-tasks-for-same-form (forked)]

Comment: what if we have async const the this instead of function like change `function handlesubmit_task1(event) { }` to `const onSubmitA = async (data) => { }` and change this `function handlesubmit_task2(event) { }` to `const onSubmitB = async (data) => { }` ? i see you have `event` and `e` but what if we passing async data like `async (data)`?

Comment: @uberrebu How are you passing the additional `data` when attaching the submit handler callback to the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler? Are you asking if you can make the `onSubmit` callback `async`? This sounds like it'd be a great new post on SO. If you decide to create a new post with accompanying [mcve] feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: yeah i will post the question as new post and let you know..thanks..you are the best react guy on SO!

Answer (score 1):

You could write it like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  function handleSubmitTask1() {
    console.log("Execute Task1");
  }

  function handleSubmitTask2() {
    console.log("Execute Task2");
  }

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        const buttonName = e.nativeEvent.submitter.name;
        if (buttonName === "button1") handleSubmitTask1();
        if (buttonName === "button2") handleSubmitTask2();
      }}
    >
      <input name="123" />

      <button type="submit" name="button1">
        task 1
      </button>
      <button type="submit" name="button2">
        task 2
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

The main point is to get the button's name which triggers the form's submission.

Comment: this also a solution. Thanks. both are solutions. and completely different approaches

Answer (score 0):

Use `onClick` on the button themselves and add `type='submit'` to submit it.

```js
export default function Formtwosubmits() {

  function handlesubmit_task1(e){


  }


  function handlesubmit_task2(e){


  }


  return (
    <>
      <form >
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit" onClick={handlesubmit_task1}>
          task 1
        </Button>

        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit" onClick={handlesubmit_task2}>
          task 2
        </Button>
        .... here input fields
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: check my edited question. i have tried this, then form validation is not done

Comment: you are using `"handlesubmit_task1"` inverted commas instead of curly braces around it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, using `event.nativeEvent.submitter.id`:

Form (note the id property value is distinct for each button):

```
<form onSubmit={this.testHandle}>
  <input type="submit" id="btn1" value="Submit button 1" />
  <input type="submit" id="btn2" value="Submit button 2" />
</form>
```

Handler:

```
testHandle(event) {
  console.log(event.nativeEvent.submitter.id);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

It successfully prints in the console `btn1` or `btn2`, depending on which button of the Form you click.

Note: using React 18.2.0.